# How does the Enumeration.Value of a scala enumeration knows the name of the member?

Tags: scala

In Scala, you can create an enumeration like this:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  val Monday, Tuesday = Value
}
```

You can call toString() to get the name of a member at runtime

```
val name = WeekDay.Monday.toString // name = "Monday"
```

How is this possible? Value is just a method that creates a new object all the time, how can this method access the name of the declared member without help of the compiler? This is pure Scala magic for me.

Comment: Reflection: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L156